# socket closed by remote peer gcdasyncsocket

Tags: ios, sockets, mqtt, openfire, xmppframework

Creating an chat application using xmppframework. When ever I try to connect to the server it connects & disconnected immediately & throws the following error.

```
error domain=gcdasyncsocketerrordomain code=7 socket closed by remote peer
```

It happens the same on Adium (chat app) software. Wondering any thing set wrong while setupping the Openfire on AWS Server.

https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/50643

Please let me know If I need to follow any steps or such.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You must store the new socket when the delegate method socket:didAcceptNewSocket been invoked

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *socketsArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _socketsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket {
    [_socketsArray addObject:newSocket];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when i try to use 1885 port numer.

I have added below code in my existing code:

```
mqttReference?.dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
        //mqttReference?.logLevel = .debug
        mqttReference?.enableSSL = true
        mqttReference?.sslSettings = [
            GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true),
            GCDAsyncSocketUseCFStreamForTLS: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
            kCFStreamSSLPeerName as String: "" as NSString,
            GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol1.rawValue)),
            GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMax: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol12.rawValue)),
        ]
```

My complete code now:

```
//  let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    mqttReference = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "", host: mqttProfile.baseURL, port: UInt16(mqttProfile.port))
    mqttReference?.username = mqttProfile.userName
    mqttReference?.password = mqttProfile.password
    mqttReference?.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
    
    
    mqttReference?.dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    //mqttReference?.logLevel = .debug
    mqttReference?.enableSSL = true
    mqttReference?.sslSettings = [
        GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true),
        GCDAsyncSocketUseCFStreamForTLS: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
        kCFStreamSSLPeerName as String: "" as NSString,
        GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol1.rawValue)),
        GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMax: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol12.rawValue)),
    ]
    
    
    mqttReference?.autoReconnect = true
    mqttReference?.backgroundOnSocket = mqttProfile.allowBackgroundMQTT
    mqttReference?.delegate = self
    do {
        if((mqttReference?.connect())!){
           ...........
```

```
Now it's working fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this github link,

[Socket closed by remote peer" - GCDAsyncSocket Error Code 7](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/131)

It is due to server might be closing the connection because of the idle period. you need to send continues ping to server.

As said in answer ,

Two reasons when the server closes the connection:

> 1. You are not sending regular pings if the client idle.
> 2. You are logging in from some different client with the same credentials, and in the server settings have the setting:
>      *Always kick* - If there is a resource conflict, immediately kick the other resource. in Server>server settings>resource policy.